# Ford Fulkerson Algorithm DFS/BFS issue

Tags: java, algorithm, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, ford-fulkerson

I am trying to implement the Ford Fulkerson Algorithm and have been getting stuck in an infinite loop when either doing my BFS or DFS solution.  I am unsure if the bug is in one of those methods or my augment algorithm.  Here is the code for each class I am working with.

Graph.java

```
    /**
 * Author - Kobie Arndt
 */

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {
    
    public Map<String, ArrayList<Edge>> map;   // keys are nodes
                                               // each node maps to an
                                               // list of Edges where the
                                               // node is the source
    public int flow;       // the flow from s -> t in this graph right now

     /**
     * Construct a Graph object
     * @param none
     */
    public Graph() {
    this.map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Edge>>();
    }

    /**
     * add a new node to this Graph
     * @param node - is just a string label
     */ 
    public void addNode(String node) {
    this.map.put(node, new ArrayList<Edge>());
    }

    /**
     * add a new edge to this graph
     * @param node - String - add this edge to nodes adjacency list
     * @param e - Edge to add
     */ 
    public void addEdge(String node, Edge e) {
    ArrayList<Edge> list;
        list = map.get(node);
    list.add(e);
        map.put(node,list);
    }

    /**
     * Get set of nodes (all string labels) for this graph
    @return Set of Strings (nodes) in this graph
     */ 
    public Set<String> getNodes (){
    return map.keySet();
    }

    /**
     * Get set of nodes (all string labels) for this graph
    @return Set of Strings (nodes) in this graph
     */     
    public ArrayList<Edge> getEdges (String n) {
    return map.get(n);
    }


    /**
     *  @return String representation of this Graph, includes the current flow
     */         
    public String toString() {
    String result = "G_" + this.flow + "\n";
    Set<String> nodes = this.map.keySet();
    for (String n : nodes) {
        result += n + "=" + this.map.get(n) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
    }

    /**
     *  @return a residual graph corresponding to this Graph
     */             
    public ResGraph getResidual() {

    ResGraph graphR = new ResGraph();
    Set<String> nodes = this.getNodes();
    for (String n : nodes)
        graphR.addNode(n);

        for (String n : nodes) {
            ArrayList<Edge> edgeList = this.getEdges(n);
        for (Edge e : edgeList) {
        if (e.capacity == e.flow) 
            graphR.addEdge(e.dest, new EdgeB(e.dest, e.source,
                           e.capacity, e.capacity));
        else if (e.flow == 0){
            graphR.addEdge(n, new EdgeF(e.source, e.dest,
                        e.capacity,  e.capacity));
        }
        else {
            graphR.addEdge(n,
                   new EdgeF(e.source, e.dest, e.capacity,
                         e.capacity-e.flow));
            graphR.addEdge(e.dest,
                   new EdgeB(e.dest, e.source, e.capacity, e.flow));
        }
        }
    }

    graphR.flow = this.flow;
    return graphR;      
    }


    /**
     *  @return augment(update) this graph with the new path
     */             
    public void augment(ArrayList<Edge> path) {
    // if the path is empty, there is no update to this graph
        if (path.size() <=0) return;

        int b = bottleNeck(path);
        System.out.println("b" + b);

        for (Edge e: path) {
            if (e == pickOut(path, e.dest)) {
                System.out.println("TRUE");
                this.flow += b;
            } else {

                this.flow -= b;
            }


        }

        // update the flow of this graph with the bottleneck in the path
        this.flow +=b;
    }

    /**
     *  @return pick out and return an edge from this adjacency
     *      list given the destination node
     */             
    private Edge pickOut(ArrayList<Edge> edgeList, String dest) {
    for (Edge e : edgeList)
        if (dest.equals(e.dest)) 
        return e;
    return null;

    }

    /**
     *  @return given a path (a listed of Edges), return
     *     the bottleneck
     */                 
    private int bottleNeck(ArrayList<Edge> path) {
    int n = path.size();
    int minFlow = path.get(0).flow;
        for (int i =1; i < n; i++) {
        int flow = path.get(i).flow;
        if (flow < minFlow)
        minFlow = flow;
    }
    return minFlow;
    }
}

// There is a residual graph for every graph

class ResGraph extends Graph{

    /*
     *  @return String representation of this Graph, includes the current flow
     */         
    public String toString() {
    String result = "G_" + this.flow + "^R\n";  
    Set<String> nodes = this.map.keySet();
    for (String n : nodes) {
        result += n + "=" + this.map.get(n) + "\n";
    }
    return result;
    }

    // FINISH ONE OF THE FOLLOWING METHODS, either DFS or BFS
    /**
     *  @param source node for search
     *  @param target node for search
     *  @return a path from the source node to the target node
     *          which is a list of Edges
     *          returns an empty path[] if there is no path
     *          uses DFS
     */             
    public ArrayList <Edge> DFS(String source, String target) {
        ArrayList<String> Stack = new ArrayList<String>();
        Stack.add(source);
        ArrayList<String> visited = new ArrayList<String>();
        visited.add(source);
        ArrayList<Edge> path = new ArrayList<Edge>();

        while (!Stack.isEmpty() && !target.equals(Stack.get(Stack.size() - 1))) {
            String current = Stack.get(Stack.size() - 1);
            System.out.println("Current " + current);
            ArrayList<Edge> listOfEdges = getEdges(current);
            int index = 0;
            boolean isGoodEdge = false;
            while (!isGoodEdge && index < listOfEdges.size()) {
                Edge currentEdge = listOfEdges.get(index);
                System.out.println("current edge " + currentEdge);
                if (Objects.equals(currentEdge.source, current) && !visited.contains(currentEdge.dest) && currentEdge.capacity > 0) {
                    isGoodEdge = true;
                    System.out.println("DEST " + currentEdge.dest);
                    Stack.add(currentEdge.dest);
                    visited.add(currentEdge.dest);
                    path.add(currentEdge);
                }
                index++;
            }
            if(!isGoodEdge){
                Stack.remove(Stack.size()-1);
                path.remove(path.size() - 1);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(path);
        // FINISH ME
    
    return new ArrayList<Edge>(); // dummy return value of
                                  // empty list which signals no path   
    }

    public ArrayList<Edge> bfsHelper(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        ArrayList<Edge> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = strings.size() - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            ArrayList<Edge> edges = this.map.get(strings.get(i - 1));
            for (Edge e : edges) {
                if (Objects.equals(e.dest, strings.get(i))) {
                    System.out.println("HERE");
                    result.add(0, e);
                    System.out.println("RESULT " + result);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     *  @param source node for search
     *  @param target node for search
     *  @return a path from the source node to the target node
     *          which is a list of Edges
     *          returns an empty path[] if there is no path
     *          uses BFS
     */             
    public ArrayList <Edge> BFS(String source, String target) {

//      ArrayList<Edge> path = new ArrayList<Edge>();
//      Set<String> nodes = getNodes();
//      boolean[] visited = new boolean[nodes.size()];
//
//      for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
//          visited[i] = false;
//      }
//
//      LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
//      queue.add(source);
//      path = getEdges(source);
//
//
//      for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {
//          if (nodes.toArray()[i] == source) {
//              visited[i] = true;
//          }
//      }
//
//      while (queue.size() != 0) {
//          String u = queue.poll();
//          for (int v = 0; v < nodes.size(); v++) {
//              if (!visited[v]) {
//                  System.out.println(nodes.toArray()[v]);
//                  System.out.println(getEdges((String) nodes.toArray()[v]));
//                  queue.add((String) nodes.toArray()[v]);
//                  System.out.println(path);
//                  visited[v] = true;
//                  //path.add(getEdges((String) nodes.toArray()[v]));
//              }
//          }
//      }

        ArrayList<Edge> result = new ArrayList<>();
        if (source.equals(target)) {
            result = getEdges(source);
            return result;
        }

        Queue<ArrayList<String>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();


        strings.add(source);
        queue.add(strings);

        while (queue.size() != 0) {
            System.out.println("queue " + queue);
            ArrayList<String> path = queue.poll();
            String current = path.get(path.size() - 1);
            System.out.println(current);
            if (Objects.equals(current, target)) {
                return bfsHelper(path);
            }
            ArrayList<Edge> edges = this.map.get(current);
            for (Edge e : edges) {
                ArrayList<String> newPath = new ArrayList<>(path);
                if (!path.contains((e.dest))) {
                    result.add(e);
                    System.out.println("RESULT " + result);
                    newPath.add(e.dest);
                    queue.add(newPath);
                }
            }

//          for (Edge e : edges) {
//
//              ArrayList<String> newPath = new ArrayList<>(path);
//              if (!path.contains(e.dest)) {
//                  newPath.add(e.dest);
//                  queue.add(newPath);
//              }
//          }


            // or FINISH ME


        }

        return new ArrayList<Edge>(); // dummy return value of
        // empty list which signals no path
    }

}
```

Edge.java

```
    import java.util.*;

public class Edge {

    public String source;  // source node
    public String dest;    // destination node
    public int capacity;   // flow capacity c_e for this edge
    public int flow;       // the actual flow on this edge

    /**
     * Construct a Graph object
     * @param source  - a node
     * @param dest - a destination node
     * @param capacity - of this edge
     * @param flow - current flow in this edge
     *    constructs a new edge from source to dest with the given
     *    capacity and flow
     */
    public Edge (String source, String dest, int capacity, int flow){
    this.source = source;
    this.dest = dest;
    this.capacity = capacity; 
    this.flow = flow;     
    }

    /**
     *  @return a string representation of this edge as s->d (cap) flow
     */
    public String toString() {
    return this.source + "->"+ this.dest +
        " (" + this.capacity +") " + this.flow;
    }
}

// forward edge this should only be used in residual graphs
class EdgeF extends Edge {

    public EdgeF (String source, String dest, int capacity, int flow){
    super(source, dest, capacity, flow);
    }

    public String toString() {
    return "E_F: "+ this.source + "->"+ this.dest + " " + this.flow;
    }
}

// backward edge this should only be used in residual graphs
class EdgeB extends Edge {

     public EdgeB (String source, String dest, int capacity, int flow){
    super(source, dest, capacity, flow);
    }
    
    public String toString() {
    return "E_B: "+ this.source + "->"+ this.dest + " " + this.flow;
    }
}
```

FindFlow.java

```
import java.util.*;
```

import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.ErrorManager;

public class FindFlow {

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
// get the number of nodes in graph (first line of file)
int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

// construct new empty graph
    Graph graph = new Graph();

// add nodes to this graph
String source = sc.nextLine();
graph.addNode(source);
for (int i = 1; i < n-1; i++) {
    String node = sc.nextLine();
    graph.addNode(node);
}
String dest = sc.nextLine();
graph.addNode(dest);

// add edges to this graph, each edge has source, dest, capacity
// and starts off with a flow of 0
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String [] tokens = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        String s = tokens[0]; //get edge source
        String d = tokens[1]; // get edge dest
    int capacity = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
    graph.addEdge(s, new Edge(s, d, capacity,0));
}
// right now the graph is G_0

ArrayList <Edge> path = new ArrayList<Edge>();
    do {
    // when printed, each graph prints its current flow
        System.out.println(graph);
    // get the residual graph
    // the first residual graph will be G_0^R
        ResGraph resGraph = graph.getResidual();
    // when printed, each graph prints what graph it is the
    // residual for
        System.out.println(resGraph);
    // find a path in the residual graph, use either DFS or BFS
    // comment out the one you do not want
    //  path = resGraph.BFS(source,dest);

        path = resGraph.DFS(source, dest);
        //print the path
        System.out.println("path = " + path + "\n");
    // update (that is augment) the graph with the new path
    // if the new path is empty, no augmentation happens
        graph.augment(path);
        //throw new Error();
        //throw new Error();
} while (path.size() > 0);

}
```

}

Example Input

```
4
s
u
v
t
s u 20
s v 10
u t 10
u v 30
v t 20
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please [edit] your post and fix the code indentation. Include hard-coded test data to make your code more of an [mre]. You may find this post useful: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)